# Template the Chart.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I would like to template values in my Chart.yaml file.
For example, `version: {{ .Values.version }}` instead of `version: 0.1.0`

For other yaml files, the above would work. However, it's my understanding that Helm treats the Chart.yaml differently and **the Chart.yaml file is not run through the templating engine**.

Does anyone know a workaround?

The actual error I get if I try to helm lint this (with `version: 0.1.0` as an entry in my values.yaml file) is: 
`error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.version":interface {}(nil)}`

Comment: Does anyone know if there's official documentation for this: "**the Chart.yaml file is not run through the templating engine**"?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the problem backward: specify the version in `Chart.yaml` and *derive* the version in wherever you are using it in the templates; you can't have a dynamic version in the `Chart.yaml` because `helm repo index .` does not accept `--set` or any such flag and thus couldn't construct the tgz to upload

Thus, given a `Chart.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
name: my-awesome-chart
appVersion: 0.1.0
version: 1.2.3
```

and a `Deployment.yaml` template:

```
{{ $myTag := .Chart.Version }}
{{/* or, you can use .Chart.AppVersion */}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.example.com:{{ $myTag }}
        # produces: docker.example.com:1.2.3
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it is backwards thinking.  I'm guessing that the author implied that an app version changes every time new binaries are produced.  If app version represents the version of SW being deployed within a pod then that is a dynamic number that changes often in a devsecops environment.  I don't see how the answer addresses that concern at all.